# why does the temperature of spray cans always feel cooler than the temperature of the environment?

Tags: pressure, everyday-life

I know why sprayed gas is cooler due to evaporation thru different pressures, but I can't understand why is the can temperature always lower than environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The can is acting as a compact heat pipe. When you grasp the can, the liquified gas inside the can absorbs the heat from your hand and expands, carrying the heat away in convective currents that dissipate the heat to other parts of the surface that are at a lower temperature than your hand. Since it draws heat from your hand it feels cool to the touch.